# Unable to swap scam token on uniswap

Tags: tokens, erc-20, uniswap

I think I have been scammed with a fake token on uniswap. Yesterday I bought a safepal token in exchange for ethereum. After I started to suspect I tried to swap back the safepal token to ethereum. When I try to swap again to ethereum I get this message “The transaction cannot succeed due to error: Undefined. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping”. This is the contact address 0x06d05A559027FE3a405CCA1d48C4504906fB8a39 . I was reading it and I don’t understand where the swapping limitation is and if there is some chance to swap back to ethereum. If anybody can help me to recover my funds I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: if no one polices fake tokens on a decentralized exchange, does it ruin the credibility of DeFi

Comment: it has no liquidity on uniswap, you cannot do it there anymore there.
https://info.uniswap.org/pair/0x2BD33aAeF324ACd68f58e40Cf5Ebbf9f11911C13

Comment: I do not know if you resolved it, but I had the same issue and the solution was to increase Slippage (to 6.1% for me).

Comment: have you got any solution as I am facing the same issue